SingleChildScrollView in Flutter Dart
I have a table with data get from API, i create a Scrollable  table with Fix First Row (which is the column header) table was successfull and function but it's always show this message in debug console:
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════
Incorrect use of ParentDataWidget.
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
Please help me to improve the code so the "Exception caught by widgets library...." not showing up when i access the table.
The code is like this:
// ignore_for_file: camel_case_types, prefer_interpolation_to_compose_strings

import 'package:bps_cilacap/restAPI/repository_penduduk_kecamatan.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:bps_cilacap/format_angka.dart';

class JumlahPendudukKecamatanA extends StatefulWidget {
  const JumlahPendudukKecamatanA({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<JumlahPendudukKecamatanA> createState() =>
      _JumlahPendudukKecamatanAState();
}

RepositoryJumlahPendudukKecamatan jumlahPendudukKecamatan =
    RepositoryJumlahPendudukKecamatan();

class _JumlahPendudukKecamatanAState extends State<JumlahPendudukKecamatanA> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final screenHeight = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height -
        MediaQuery.of(context).padding.top -
        MediaQuery.of(context).padding.bottom;
    // ignore: unused_local_variable
    final screenWidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width -
        MediaQuery.of(context).padding.left -
        MediaQuery.of(context).padding.right;
    return Scaffold(
        body: FutureBuilder(
      future: jumlahPendudukKecamatan.getData(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasData) {
          List isipendudukkecamatan = snapshot.data as List;
          return PageView.builder(
            itemCount: 1,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              String kec1 = "  1. " + isipendudukkecamatan[index = 0].kecamatan;
              String kec2 = "  2. " + isipendudukkecamatan[index = 1].kecamatan;
              …
    ……
              String kec24 =24. " + isipendudukkecamatan[index = 23].kecamatan;
              String kab = " " + isipendudukkecamatan[index = 24].kecamatan;

              int lk1 = int.parse(isipendudukkecamatan[index = 0].lk1);
              int lk2 = int.parse(isipendudukkecamatan[index = 1].lk1);
              ……
    …..              
              int lk24 = int.parse(isipendudukkecamatan[index = 23].lk1);
              int lkTotal = int.parse(isipendudukkecamatan[index = 24].lk1);

              int pr1 = int.parse(isipendudukkecamatan[index = 0].pr1);
              int pr2 = int.parse(isipendudukkecamatan[index = 1].pr1);
              int pr3 = int.parse(isipendudukkecamatan[index = 2].pr1);
              ………
    ………
int pr24 = int.parse(isipendudukkecamatan[index = 23].pr1);
              int prTotal = int.parse(isipendudukkecamatan[index = 24].pr1);

             
          return Scaffold(
                body: Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                 
//This is the part of Fixed Row Header
Row(
                    children: [
                      Flexible(
                        fit: FlexFit.tight,
                        flex: 4,
                        child: Container(
                          height: screenHeight * 0.06,
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                              horizontal: 2, vertical: 10),
                          color: Colors.green,
                          child: const Center(
                            child: Text(
                              "Kecamatan",
                              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                              style: TextStyle(
                                  color: Colors.white,
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      Flexible(
                        fit: FlexFit.tight,
                        flex: 2,
                        child: Container(
                          height: screenHeight * 0.06,
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                              horizontal: 2, vertical: 10),
                          color: Colors.green,
                          child: const Center(
                            child: Text(
                              "Lk",
                              style: TextStyle(
                                  color: Colors.white,
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      Flexible(
                        fit: FlexFit.tight,
                        flex: 2,
                        child: Container(
                          height: screenHeight * 0.06,
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                              horizontal: 2, vertical: 10),
                          color: Colors.green,
                          child: const Center(
                            child: Text(
                              "Pr",
                              style: TextStyle(
                                  color: Colors.white,
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      Flexible(
                        fit: FlexFit.tight,
                        flex: 2,
                        child: Container(
                          height: screenHeight * 0.06,
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                              horizontal: 2, vertical: 10),
                          color: Colors.green,
                          child: const Center(
                            child: Text(
                              "Lk + Pr",
                              style: TextStyle(
                                  color: Colors.white,
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                                   
 
 // This the part of Scrollable Row

Expanded(
                    child: SingleChildScrollView(
                    child: Flexible(
                      child: SizedBox(
                        width: screenWidth,
                        height: screenHeight,
                        child: Column(
                          children: [
                            //First Row
                            Container(
                              width: screenWidth * 1.0,
                              height: screenHeight * 0.032,
                              color: Colors.transparent,
                              child: Row(
                                children: [
                                  Flexible(
                                    fit: FlexFit.tight,
                                    flex: 4,
                                    child: Container(
                                      color: Colors.transparent,
                                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                                          right: 10, top: 1, bottom: 1),
                                      child: Text(
                                        kec1,
                                        textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                                        style: const TextStyle(
                                            fontWeight: FontWeight.normal),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  Flexible(
                                    fit: FlexFit.tight,
                                    flex: 2,
                                    child: Container(
                                      color: Colors.transparent,
                                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                                          right: 10, top: 1, bottom: 1),
                                      child: Text(
                                        Format.convertTo(lk1, 0),
                                        textAlign: TextAlign.right,
                                        style: const TextStyle(
                                            fontWeight: FontWeight.normal),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  Flexible(
                                    fit: FlexFit.tight,
                                    flex: 2,
                                    child: Container(
                                      color: Colors.transparent,
                                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                                          right: 10, top: 1, bottom: 1),
                                      child: Text(
                                        Format.convertTo(pr1, 0),
                                        textAlign: TextAlign.right,
                                        style: const TextStyle(
                                            fontWeight: FontWeight.normal),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  Flexible(
                                    fit: FlexFit.tight,
                                    flex: 2,
                                    child: Container(
                                      color: Colors.transparent,
                                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                                          right: 5, top: 1, bottom: 1),
                                      child: Text(
                                        Format.convertTo((lk1 + pr2), 0),
                                        textAlign: TextAlign.right,
                                        style: const TextStyle(
                                            fontWeight: FontWeight.normal),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ],
                              ),
                            ),

                            //Second row
                            ……
                           //And more row here
                            …
                            //21 st row
                       ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ))
                ],
              ));
            },
          );
        }
        if (snapshot.hasError) {
          return const Text('Database Error');
        } else {
          return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator(strokeWidth: 3));
        }
      },
    ));
  }
}


i'm hping removing this message (althoug the table function normally)
════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════
Incorrect use of ParentDataWidget.

I solved this (working around) by using two tables instead of one, the first table will have only the headers row while the second table below will have the content rows only.
Edited with example:
I would not use rows and columns for Api to get all data representation while we have Table (or custom table widgets) in Flutter, the only problem was that we can't pin the header row of the table and that is why I suggest this workaround : gif example
Column(
      children: [
        // Header Table
        Table(
          border: TableBorder.all(),
          children: [
            TableRow(
              children: [
                TableCell(child: Center(child: Text('Header 1'))),
                TableCell(child: Center(child: Text('Header 2'))),
                TableCell(child: Center(child: Text('Header 3'))),
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
        // Content Table wrapped in a SingleChildScrollView
        Expanded(
          child: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Table(
              border: TableBorder.all(),
              children: List.generate(200, (index) {
                return TableRow(
                  children: [
                    TableCell(child: Center(child: Text('Row $index - Col 1'))),
                    TableCell(child: Center(child: Text('Row $index - Col 2'))),
                    TableCell(child: Center(child: Text('Row $index - Col 3'))),
                  ],
                );
              }),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],


Could you please show me how to do it?  How to change the code that  i use?

sorry for the late response; put Column in your Scaffold body then, the first child of the column should be the header table only one row and the second child will be only content rows without a header row I will edit my answer for more clarification.
